# java mail msgsend error

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am using JavamailAPI, I downloaded and installed the javamail-1.4.4 and jaf-1.1.1.
Added the mail.jar and activation.jar to the CLASSPATH. Ii am able to compile the msgsend class, when i trying to run the msgsend class i am getting the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: msgsend/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: msgsend.java
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: msgsend.java.  Program will exit.
```

Please any can help me in solving this issue.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to launch your program by

```
java msgsend.java
```

but the java expects a class name, not a file name.

```
java msgsend
```

Also, class names in Java should be upper-case.

Comment: i am running using java msgsend, not included .java extension. Then also its giving the same error

Comment: Are you sure it is exactly the same?

Comment: yes...Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: msgsend
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: msgsend
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: msgsend.  Program will exit.

Comment: No it's not. Now it says "msgsend" not "msgsend/java". You need ensure that your class is in the classpath. Use 

    java -cp path/to/a/dir/with/your/class msgsend

Comment: Just follow a tutorial how to use java, e.g.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to compile your `msgsend.java` using `javac` and then run it as follows:

```
java msgsend
```

See that I removed the `.java` extension as java will look for `msgend.class`.

Comment: I am running as java msgsend, but still getting the same error, any other reasons, please tell me.

Comment: Did you **compile** the java file first?